# Visual studio 2012 ASP.NET webadminfiles error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

Hi so I am trying to create a login form for my website but when I open the ASP.NET configuration it gives me an error.

Server Error in '/asp.netwebadminfiles' Application.

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0122: 'System.Configuration.StringUtil' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Source Error:

```
Line 987:
Line 988:             // Put together some unique app id
Line 989:             string appId = StringUtil.GetNonRandomizedHashCode(String.Concat(appPath, appPhysPath)).ToString("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Line 990:
Line 991:
```

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\App_Code\WebAdminPage.cs    Line: 989

Compiler Warning Messages:

Warning: CS0628: 'System.Web.Administration.WebAdminRemotingManager.ApplicationMetaPath': new protected member declared in sealed class
Source Error:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\App_Code\WebAdminPage.cs  

Line 930:        }
Line 931:        
Line 932:        protected string ApplicationMetaPath {
Line 933:            get {
Line 934:                return _applicationMetaPath;
```

Show detailed Compiler Output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Users\gabchan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\asp.netwebadminfiles\988e0dc5\b210afcc\App_GlobalResources.qk47jmml.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /out:"C:\Users\gabchan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\asp.netwebadminfiles\988e0dc5\b210afcc\App_Code.rcuj7mgk.dll" /debug- /optimize+ /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /warnaserror-  "C:\Users\gabchan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\asp.netwebadminfiles\988e0dc5\b210afcc\App_Code.rcuj7mgk.0.cs" "C:\Users\gabchan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\asp.netwebadminfiles\988e0dc5\b210afcc\App_Code.rcuj7mgk.1.cs" "C:\Users\gabchan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\asp.netwebadminfiles\988e0dc5\b210afcc\App_Code.rcuj7mgk.2.cs" "C:\Users\gabchan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\asp.netwebadminfiles\988e0dc5\b210afcc\App_Code.rcuj7mgk.3.cs" "C:\Users\gabchan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\asp.netwebadminfiles\988e0dc5\b210afcc\App_Code.rcuj7mgk.4.cs" "C:\Users\gabchan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\asp.netwebadminfiles\988e0dc5\b210afcc\App_Code.rcuj7mgk.5.cs" "C:\Users\gabchan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\asp.netwebadminfiles\988e0dc5\b210afcc\App_Code.rcuj7mgk.6.cs" "C:\Users\gabchan\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\asp.netwebadminfiles\988e0dc5\b210afcc\App_Code.rcuj7mgk.7.cs"


Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.6.0079.0

for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.



This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\App_Code\WebAdminPage.cs(932,26): warning CS0628: 'System.Web.Administration.WebAdminRemotingManager.ApplicationMetaPath': new protected member declared in sealed class
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\App_Code\WebAdminPage.cs(989,29): error CS0122: 'System.Configuration.StringUtil' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Please help. I've tried the command line solution already and it doesn't work

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\
v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/asp.netwebadminfiles" /port:[PORT] /clr:4.0 /ntlm

http://localhost:[port]/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=[Exact_Project_Path]\&applicationUrl=/
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET webadminfiles are not usable in windows 10 so downgrade your OS to a previous Windows version